# Open Source Project That can turn RSS feeds into newspaper style layouts

Tags: open-source

Has anyone come across any open-source projects that take RSS feeds and display then in [newspaper style layouts](http://www.zurb.com/playground/newspaper-layout#)?

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for SO. if it isn't — my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an open-source project that does this but i've stumbled accross bit and pieces which can be used in conjunction with each other to create this.

For the client side layout, one could achieve this by using [jqMasonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/).

For the server side stuff, one could use any feed parsing library. e.g Python has f[eed parser](http://feedparser.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [sux0](http://www.sux0r.org/)r. It parses rss feeds, classifies them and display them.